# Select users associated to Approved list/table using Ms Access 2003/2013 or Sql query

Tags: mysql, sql, ms-access, ms-access-2003, ms-access-2013

**[Users]**

```
ID  |   UserID  |   City    |   Phone
----+-----------+-----------+----------
1   |   John    |   Rome    |   12345
2   |   Tom     |   Oslo    |   12345
3   |   Simon   |   Bogota  |   12345
4   |   Kurt    |   Tokyo   |   12345
```

**[Orders]**

```
ID  |   UserID  |   OrderNr |   OrderName
------------------------------------------------
1   |   John    |   1       |   Apple
2   |   John    |   2       |   Carrots
3   |   John    |   3       |   Banana
4   |   Tom     |   3       |   Banana
5   |   Tom     |   1       |   Apple
6   |   Tom     |   8       |   Raisins
7   |   Simon   |   3       |   Banana
8   |   Simon   |   1       |   Apple
9   |   Kurt    |   7       |   Cucumber
```

**Approved List**

```
1 (Apple)
3 (Banana)
4 (Another order)
8 (Raisins)
```

Now i would like to select all Users who's orders only contains/matches my approved list.

John should be excluded in this case because he ordered Carrots which has OrderNr 2 that is not in my approved list.

Comment: And when does MySQL come into the picture?

Comment: Rename Users' column UserID to UserName. In Orders table, store the ID from the Users table instead of the UserName. Don't have both ID and OrderNr in Orders table, and don't allow duplicates. Add another table, OrderItems where the different order items are listed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want users who *only* have orders in the approved list, I would suggest conditional aggregation and a `having` clause:

```
select o.userid
from orders as o
group by o.userid
having sum(iif(o.OrderNr not in (1, 3, 4, 8), 1, 0)) = 0;
```

The `having` clause filters out users who have an "unapproved" product.